# Why isn't this Ruby calculator working as intended?

Tags: ruby, calculator

This code is intended to be a basic calculator with some features not yet added.

Whenever this is run the two beginning `puts` display, but when the program receives user input it closes.

Is there anything fundamentally wrong? I tried debugging for ~1 hour now and I have given up.

```
puts "Hello There. What you you like to calculate?"
puts "You have the option of Distance, Slope, Pythag, Fibonacci, and Sales Tax"
calculationSelection = gets

if calculationSelection == "Distance"
  puts "You have selected Distance"
  puts "Please enter x2"
  x2 = gets
  puts "Please enter x1"
  x1 = gets
  puts "Please enter y2"
  y2 = gets
  puts "Please enter y1"
  y1 = gets

  Distance = Math.sqrt((x2.to_f - x1.to_f)**2 + (y2.to_f - y1.to_f)**2)
  print "Your distance is: "
  puts Distance.to_s
  pause
elsif calculationSelection == "Slope"
  puts "You have selected Slope"
  puts "Enter x of Point One"
  x1 = gets
  puts "Enter y of Point One"
  y1 = gets
  puts "Enter x of Point Two"
  x2 = gets
  puts "Enter y of Point Two"
  y2 = gets

  Slope = (x1.to_f - x2.to_f) / (y1.to_f - y2.to_f)
  print "Your slope is: "
  puts Slope.to_s 
  pause
end
```

Comment: **Hint:** Try to put an else in the end and print `p "OMG! It works"`

Comment: Clearly, there is something fundamentally wrong. But we here are not a free code-debugging service. Please read the manual on how to ask good questions, and either edit this question or post another question that states specifically how we can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In Ruby we don't use camelCase for variables, instead we use snake_case; ItIsA readability_thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to put `chomp` at the end of the `gets` to strip the returned value:

```
gets.chomp
```

Then you will enter the "Distance" and the "Slope" you also need to watch for the case. You can also match everything with a `downcase` in your conditional statement to remove case sensitivity.