# Ruby Get a operator and make it work as one

Tags: ruby, operation

Noob to the extreme here.

How can I make this operator work?

```
puts "Tell me a number"
num1 = gets
puts "Tell me an another number"
num2 = gets
puts "Tell me an operator"
op = gets

puts num1.to_i op num2.to_i
```

Comment: You can find a similar example in this questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31331287/no-method-error-ruby-calculator or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38649405/making-ruby-calculator-run-continuously or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25572500/why-isnt-this-ruby-calculator-working-as-intended

Comment: Thanks so much @knut, but is there a way to convert "+" into a operator, but using gets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby an operator is basically a method.  Do this:

```
puts num1.to_i.public_send(op.chomp, num2.to_i)
```

With [`Object#public_send`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/Object.html#method-i-public_send), you can send a (public) method specified either with String or Symbol.
Note if your Ruby version is old, you may need replace `public_send` with `send`.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in other answers, you can use `send` (or `public_send`) to call a method.

There is one problem: `gets` includes a newline (e.g. `+\n`). The `to_i` method can handle this. `send` tries to find a methos with the newline (and will not find it). So you have to remove the newline from operator (using the `strip`-method.

So the complete example:

```
puts "Tell me a number"
num1 = gets
puts "Tell me an another number"
num2 = gets
puts "Tell me an operator"
op = gets

puts num1.to_i.send( op.strip,  num2.to_i)
```

I would recommend to convert the values immediate after reading it, it makes life easier later:

```
puts "Tell me a number"
num1 = gets.to_i
puts "Tell me an another number"
num2 = gets.to_i
puts "Tell me an operator"
op = gets.strip

puts num1.public_send( op,  num2)
```

Be aware, there is no check for valid operators. When you enter

```
1
2
u
```

you get a `undefined method 'u' for 1:Integer (NoMethodError)`-error.

Comment: `num1 = 2
num2 = 3
op = +

puts (num1 op.public_send num2)` 

Thanks so much for taking the time. 
Why my code above won´t work?

Comment: Why should it? I guess there are some newlines missing. You can replace it with a semicolon. I guess you look for `num1 = 2 ; num2 = 3 ; op = '+' ; puts num1.public_send(op, num2)` Error 1: plus must be a string. Error 2: `public_send`is a method of Integer (here num1). - Bus this is a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The `public_send` method shared already works perfectly well but here is an alternative way.

```
puts num1.to_i.method(op.chomp).(num2.to_i)
```

It basically does the exact same thing using [`Object#method`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Object.html#method-i-method) and [`Method#call`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Method.html#method-i-call). I found this out thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019668/ruby-string-to-operator) and [@ArapRakshit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2767755/arup-rakshit) where I got the answers I needed.